# What do I need to set up to be able to run this as a CLI as shown in the readme?

Tags: command-line-interface

https://github.com/slang800/instagram-screen-scrape

In one of the examples it shows the author using this as a CLI inside the terminal, I'm unable to do so.

`$ instagram-screen-scrape posts --username carrotcreative`

What needs to be done to be able to run it as shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all that was necessary was to install it using `npm` (I ended up doing it globally for convenience).

`$ npm install instagram-screen-scrape -g`